# AngularJS: Call controller update function from another controller or JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have a controller that updates a portion of the screen.  Sometimes a user will do an action that will, on the server side, invalidate what that region shows.  How then, when a user clicks a button elsewhere can I make another controller update?  I have followed the usual pattern for such things i.e. :

```
appControllers.controller('linksController', ['$scope', '$filter', '$interval', function ($scope, $filter, $interval) {

    $scope.update = function () {
        // update code here... this is what I want to invoke from another function or area of JS
    }
```

Comment: Depending on which fits with your data I'd suggest using either a service which exposes shared data which can be watched, or use the pub/sub methods on the scope (emit/broadcast). I'd advocate the pub/sub approach if it's a global type of event and the rootScope makes sense to send it, otherwise the service approach would likely be better for modularity.

Comment: check out `$emit` and `$on` as noted above, or perhaps `$broadcast`.  to @MattWhipple's point, if you don't use events, use a factory.  putting everything on scope will make your code much harder to unit test.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the broadcast stuff looks promising

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may to use shared service/factory for this.

If you want to pass just loaded data from one controller to another, you can pass it through the "Shared Service" and broadcast event in it with `$broadcast/$emit` functions. Broadcasted event can be listened in any controller with `$scope.$on`.

```
   angular.module("appControllers", []).factory("sharedService", function($rootScope){

        var mySharedService = {};

        mySharedService.values = {};

        mySharedService.passData = function(newData){
            mySharedService.values = newData;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('dataPassed');
        }

        return mySharedService; 
   });

    appControllers.controller('linksController', ['$scope', 'sharedService', function ($scope, sharedService) {
       $scope.update = function(newData){
           sharedService.passData(newData);
       };
    }

   appControllers.controller('anotherController', ['$scope', 'sharedService', function ($scope, sharedService) {
       $scope.$on('dataPassed', function () {
          $scope.newItems = sharedService.values;
       });
   }
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm after. Thanks